# Tag synonym of [birt-report] to [birt]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

Can [birt-report](/questions/tagged/birt-report) be made a synonym of [birt](/questions/tagged/birt)? They refer to the same tool, but the latter is more popular (with 303 questions) than the former (79 questions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[birt-report](/questions/tagged/birt-report) has been already suggested as synonym of [birt](/questions/tagged/birt); it just needs to get enough votes.

As your score for [birt](/questions/tagged/birt) is 12, you can vote that synonym suggestion, which would need another vote to be approved as synonym.

In this way, the new questions using [birt-report](/questions/tagged/birt-report) will be re-tagged [birt](/questions/tagged/birt). To change the old questions, and make them appear as tagged [birt](/questions/tagged/birt), it is necessary to merge the tags (and keep [birt-report](/questions/tagged/birt-report) as synonym).

Comment: Where/how can we vote for this?

Comment: You can vote [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/birt/synonyms), if your score for the tag is at least 10.

Comment: There are only 7 users, with a [score of 10][1], one has been inactive for years.  Is there away around the auto count to 4?  


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/birt/topusers

Comment: I only needed a score of 5, which I have now so synonym is created :)